Why ifconfig command does not work due to permission denied when you connect to public WiFi or SSID?
This might be a bit stupid/naive question but I was at a conference event and after I connected to Free WiFi, I tried ifconfig in cmd of my cellphone and it did not work as follows:
> ifconfig
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited output.
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1  (UNSPEC)

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet XX.XX.75.132  netmask 255.255.224.0  broadcast XX.XX.95.255
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)

before writing this post I thought used ipconfig but now I'm more curious why they closed/banned ifconfig command. Do they close this command when they configure the DHCP server to provide free internet access for the public or thesis configured somewhere else? and why?

It is not something the network did. It's on your computer; there's no mechanism in either wifi or dhcp to modify file permissions.
